# Microservices, Dependencies and Events

Tags: events, dependencies, microservices

I’ve been doing a lot of googling regarding managing dependencies between microservices. We’re trying to move away from big monolithic app into micro-services in order to scale organizationally and be able to develop faster and with multiple teams working in parallel.
However, as we’re trying to functionally partition the monolith into the microservices, we see how intertwined business logic and data really is. This was not a problem when we were sitting on top of one big DB and were able to do big relational joins. But with microservices, this becomes a problem.

One solution is to make microservice-A go to 5-10 other microservices to get necessary data (this is equivalent of DB view with join). Another solution is to make microservice-A listen to events from 5-10 other services and populate local storage with relevant into (this is an equivalent of materialized view). Either way, microservice-A is coupled with 5-10 other services, and if new info is needed in microservice-A, the some of the services that it depends upon might will need to be release prior to microservice-A. Please note that microservice-A is itself depended upon by other services. Bottom line, we end up with DISTRIBUTED dependency hell.

Many articles advocate for second solution – i.e. something along the lines of Event Sourcing, Choreography, etc.

I would appreciate any shared experiences, recommendations and insights.

Philometor.

Answer (score 3):

While not technically an "answer", I can definitely share some of my observations and experiences. Your question concerning services calling other services for database operations reminded me of a project where an architect sold senior management on the idea of "decoupling" persistence from the rest of the applications by implementing hundreds of REST interfaces in what essentially was a distributed DAO pattern in front of a very large enterprise database.  The project ended up exactly the way I predicted - a dismal failure.

Microservices aren't about turning a monolithic application into a distributed monolithic application.  In my example project above, the monolith was turned into a stove-piped, fragile, chaotic mess, with the coupling only moved to service contracts instead of Java class method signatures, and with a performance hit so bad the application was unusable. Last I heard they are still running their original monolith.

Microservices should be more of a vertical partitioning of your application and not a horizontal one.  In my opinion it's better to think in terms of business function partitioning rather than "converting" an existing monolith. There's no rule that determines how big a microservice must be, but it should be big enough to do one complete synchronous function without needing to directly depend on outside services (as much as possible) to complete its work. If a microservice performs a complex business function that affects 50 tables, so be it!  It owns those many tables.  Ideally if a service goes down, it should affect only that business functionality it's responsible for, and not directly affect other services.  As you can see, this thinking is the complete opposite from that which produced the distributed mess in my project example.

Not only do you need to ensure that the motivation behind replacing monoliths with microservices is sound, but also you need to step outside the monolith and revisit the actual business and begin partitioning that instead.  Like everything else, baby steps are the way to go.  Start with one small complete business function, and convert that into a single microservice instead of trying to replace a monolith all at once.

Comment: Thanks for providing detailed explanation and relevant experience.
In my situation, upper mgmt is already sold on the idea of decoupling the big monolith. Microservices are BELIEVED to be the solution to slow release cycles, lack of business agility, etc.

in terms of dependencies between microservices, we think not only in terms of decoupling persistence, but in terms of encapsulating relevant business rules in separate microservices.

Comment: To use an example from eCommerce: orders, catalog, users, payments are not just thin facades over DB tables, but they encapsulate business rules dealing with those data at the same time, they do rely on each other - and that's the dependency that i'm worried about.

Comment: No, I don't think they rely on each other.  How does "create customer" rely on "retrieve customer order history" or "process payment" or "search product catalog"?  Sure you need to know which customer you're processing the payment for, but you need to know this information before entering that use case.  You'll need to throw out that whole concept of a relationally constrained mega-enterprise single database.  I won't fool you, you'll loose some nice conveniences by doing so, but you'll gain that flexibility and isolation.  It's a trade-off.